# OpenCV only process in real time?

Tags: java, android, opencv

Good morning everyone.

I'm learning the basics from openCV, and i came up with a question:

OpenCV only process in real time?

I mean, i cant load up a image file and "face detect" it?

I'm developing for android, and allways have to set up the callback function like this:

```
private BaseLoaderCallback mOpenCVCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
   @Override
   public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
     switch (status) {
       case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
       {
          Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
          // Create and set View
          mView = new puzzle15View(mAppContext);
          setContentView(mView);
       } break;
       default:
       {
          super.onManagerConnected(status);
       } break;
     }
   }
};
```

But i dont want to "load up camera", i simply want to load up a file, and proccess it.

Comment: I don't know how to do it in Java, so other may answer you with some code. But you definitely **can** work on a single image "offline".

Comment: I did some research, and i see that is possible. But how? Cant get any code to do so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally come to an answer...

I was loading OpenCv with BaseLoaderCallback in async mode, so it need some time to load up modules. After that i was able to use all the functions from the library.

Thanks for the help